# Limit as $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x^2\cot( x )$

Tags: limits

Why does  $x^2\cot(x)$ become $0$ as $x$ tends to $0+$?
I tried using L'Hôpital's rule but I'm not getting it! Please help!! 
I'm getting the value as infinity...I think I went wrong somewhere...please help me sort it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^2\cot(x)=\frac{x^2}{\tan(x)} $$
If we directly plug in $0$ for $x$ we get $\frac{0}{0}$. So using L'Hopital's Rule:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^2}{\tan(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2x}{\sec^2(x)} = \frac{2\cdot 0}{\sec^2(0)} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$$

Comment: Silly mistake from my side.Was a silly question.But thanks a lot for the answer :-).Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^2 \cot x = x\cos x\cdot\frac 1 {(\sin x)/x}
$$

If you can find the limits as $x\to0$ of $x$ and of $\cos x$ and of $(\sin x)/x$ then you've got it.

Comment: Could the person who down-voted this explain why?

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

Recall that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x}=1$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\cot x&=\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{\tan x}{x}}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0}x\right)\\\\
&=(1)(0)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

**METHOD 2:**

We can use asymptotics to write $\cot x=\frac1x+O(x)$.  Thus,

$$x^2\cot x=x+O(x^3)\to 0$$

---

**METHOD 3:**

And L'Hospital's Rule gives

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\cot x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x}{\sec^2 x}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as in answers and comments $$x^2\cot(x)=\frac{x^2}{\tan(x)}=x\frac{x}{\tan(x)}=\frac{x}{\frac{\tan(x)}x}$$ Another way using Taylor $$x^2\cot(x)=x^2\Big(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^3}{45}+O\left(x^4\right)\Big)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{45}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: Just like one of mine!  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV. Yes, I noticed ! I was typing when your answer came. May I confess that I am in a very deep love with Taylor (and his series !). I only use that for limits. Not being a teacher, I really do not understand why it is not more used. What I always think important is : what is the limit and how is it approached. Cheers :-)

Comment: I agree.  Expansions are often simple, and work well and efficiently in many cases.

Comment: @Dr.MV. Sorry but, for once, I don't agree with you !! They **always** work well and efficiently.